# Printing a list to new line for each set of data

Tags: python, list, printing, append

I am still learning coding so please forgive me if this is basic. I have a set of code that asks the user how many users it wants to input (x) and asks for basic information about all X of those students (first and last name, age). However, when I print it out it all comes out as one long line. I have seen a few ways to print each character to a new line but not each new set of data. I would like to separate it by user. What I currently have is:

```
Name:            Age:     
Tiger woods      40,      karen woods     33,   charlie brown    44
```

What I would like it:

```
Name:            Age:
Tiger Woods      40
Karen Woods      33
Charlie Brown    44
```

This is the code I am currently working with:

```
list.append(firstname)
list.append(lastname)
list.append(age)

print("name:       age:")
print(", ".join(map(str, list)))
```

Comment: you can print things on multiple lines by `print('\n')` which will print a newline -- try adding it to the end of each 'row' of data that you have

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `\n` in a string to start a new line. For example, if you have this `print` statement:

```
print("Hello world!\nHow are you today?")
```

It would display as:

```
Hello world!
How are you today?
```

Thus, you should simply be able to replace this:

```
print(", ".join(map(str, list)))
```

with this:

```
print("\n".join(map(str, list)))
```

or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list of touples instead a list of words

```
list.append((firstname,lastname,age))
```

edited
sorry, you can access the data through a subindex

```
you_list[0] #for firstname
you_list[2] #for age
```